# Regular expression to extract specific number from square bracket in python

Tags: python

Here is my string:

```
"ABC[5],DEF[3],GHF[1],GBM[1],NECU[1],KIR[1],LGAD[18]"
```

Given the search key as LGAD, I should get the output as 18.
I am not sure how to do that in python. Please help me with the same.

Comment: What have you tried, and how was it deficient?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
import re

text = "ABC[5],DEF[3],GHF[1],GBM[1],NECU[1],KIR[1],LGAD[18]"
key = 'LGAD'


def find(k):
    pattern = k + '\[(\d+)\]'
    match = re.search(pattern, text)
    return match.group(1)


result = find(key)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
18
```

The patterhn `k + '\[(\d+)\]'` matches the search key (`k`) followed by a group of digits wrapped between brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very well formed. I wouldn't use regexps for this.

```
ip = "ABC[5],DEF[3],GHF[1],GBM[1],NECU[1],KIR[1],LGAD[18]"             

def parse(ip):
   d = {}
   items = ip.split(",")
   for i in items:
     key, val = i.split('[')
     d[key] = int(val.strip(']'))
   return d


parsed = parse(ip)
print (parsed['LGAD'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "ABC[5],DEF[3],GHF[1],GBM[1],NECU[1],KIR[1],LGAD[18]"
rx = r'LGAD\[(\d+)\]'

m = re.search(rx, text)
print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dict` from that string, taking into account its format consistency, and then access the value you want using the word as a key:

```
string = "ABC[5],DEF[3],GHF[1],GBM[1],NECU[1],KIR[1],LGAD[18]" 
word = "LGAD"
stringDict = dict((el[:el.find('[')],int(el[el.find('[')+1:-1])) for el in string.split(','))
print(stringDict[word])
```

Output:

```
18
```

You can also do it using the `map` function:

```
stringDict = dict(map(lambda el: (el[:el.find('[')],int(el[el.find('[')+1:-1])), string.split(',')))
```